# wordcloud for a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas, classification, word-cloud

i have a csv file with 2 columns (dataframe)
column 1 contains a sentence i love banana

and column 2  contains a classe i have `5 classes`

i need a wordcloud for each class 
in fact each all the senetences corresponding to each classe it possible to do it ?
it try this code but id does not working

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cloud = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=20, stopwords=stopwords)
tuples = tuple([tuple(x) for x in df.Phrase.value_counts().reset_index().values])
a = cloud.generate_from_frequencies(tuples)

plt.imshow(a)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("a")
plt.show()
```

example of datasets

```
text                           classe
i love banana                 positive 
i hate banana                 negetive
maybe i love maybe no         neutral
bit yes bit no                not_sure
wooooooooooow                 like_it
```

Comment: @MaxU yes i modify the description

Comment: @MaxU yes i modified the description

Comment: Yes, i noticed that. I'm currently learning how `wordcloud` is working... ;)

Comment: If i understand correctly you want to have 5 images (clouds) - one per class, did i get you right?

Comment: @MaxU exactly that what i need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example for one class: `positive`.

Assuming we have the following DF:

```
In [79]: df
Out[79]:
                    text    classe
0          i love banana  positive
1             love apple  positive
2       love, love, love  positive
3          i hate banana  negative
4               it sucks  negative
5  maybe i love maybe no   neutral
6         bit yes bit no  not_sure
7          wooooooooooow   like_it
```

Solution:

```
In [80]: %paste
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

cloud = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=20, stopwords=stopwords.words('english'))

positive_cloud = cloud.generate(df.loc[df.classe == 'positive', 'text'].str.cat(sep='\n'))
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(positive_cloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
## -- End pasted text --
```

Result:

[image]

Some explanations:

generated text for a single `class`:

```
In [81]: df.loc[df.classe == 'positive', 'text'].str.cat(sep='\n')
Out[81]: 'i love banana\nlove apple\nlove, love, love'
```