# Generate word cloud from single-column Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, word-cloud

I have a Pandas dataframe with one column: Crime type. The column contains 16 different "categories" of crime, which I would like to visualise as a word cloud, with words sized based on their frequency within the dataframe.

[image]

I have attempted to do this with the following code:

To bring the data in:

```
fields = ['Crime type']

text2 = pd.read_csv('allCrime.csv', usecols=fields)
```

To generate the word cloud:

```
wordcloud2 = WordCloud().generate(text2)
# Generate plot
plt.imshow(wordcloud2)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I was able to create an earlier word cloud from the full dataset, using the following code, but I want the word cloud to only generate words from the specific column, 'crime type' ('allCrime.csv' contains approx. 13 columns):

```
text = open('allCrime.csv').read()
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
# Generate plot
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I'm new to Python and Pandas (and coding generally!) so all help is gratefully received.

Comment: you may want to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193013/wordcloud-for-a-csv-file-in-python) ...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem is that the `WordCloud.generate` method that you are using expects a string on which it will count the word instances but you provide a `pd.Series`.

Depending on what you want the word cloud to generate on you can either do:

1. `wordcloud2 = WordCloud().generate(' '.join(text2['Crime Type']))`, which would concatenate all words in your dataframe column and then count all instances.
2. Use `WordCloud.generate_from_frequencies` to manually pass the computed frequencies of words.

Comment: Thanks languitar and @MaxU - a combination of your posts worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

```
df = pd.read_csv('allCrime.csv', usecols=fields)

text = df['Crime type'].values 

wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(str(text))

plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a concatenated input text. This can be done with the `join` function.

```
fields = ['Crime type']
text2 = pd.read_csv('allCrime.csv', usecols=fields)

text3 = ' '.join(text2['Crime Type'])
wordcloud2 = WordCloud().generate(text3)
# Generate plot
plt.imshow(wordcloud2)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a word cloud while removing all the stop words for a single column.
Let's say your data frame is df and col name is comment then the following code can help:

```
#Final word cloud after all the cleaning and pre-processing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
comment_words = ' '
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS) 

# iterate through the csv file 
for val in df.comment: 
  
   # typecaste each val to string 
   val = str(val) 

   # split the value 
   tokens = val.split() 
  
# Converts each token into lowercase 
for i in range(len(tokens)): 
    tokens[i] = tokens[i].lower() 
      
for words in tokens: 
    comment_words = comment_words + words + ' '


wordcloud = WordCloud(width = 800, height = 800, 
            background_color ='white', 
            stopwords = stopwords, 
            min_font_size = 10).generate(comment_words) 

# plot the WordCloud image                        
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 8), facecolor = None) 
plt.imshow(wordcloud) 
plt.axis("off") 
plt.tight_layout(pad = 0) 

plt.show()
```

Comment: How this code is related with the above question? Have you tested the above code? The above code is not working. From where you have got df and comments? Where is the panda import? Please correct and test the code before posting.

Answer (score 2):

it can be done easily using below:

```
df = pd.read_csv('allCrime.csv')
data = df['Crime type'].value_counts().to_dict()
wc = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(data)

plt.imshow(wc)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

# Remove punctuation
df['text_proc'] = \
df['text'].map(lambda x: re.sub('[,\.!?]', '', x))

# Convert the titles to lowercase
df['text_proc'] = \
df['text_proc'].map(lambda x: x.lower())

# Print out the first rows of papers
df['text_proc'].head()


# Join the different processed titles together.
long_string = ','.join(list(df['text_proc'].values))
# Create a WordCloud object
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=5000, contour_width=3, 
contour_color='steelblue')# Generate a word cloud
wordcloud.generate(long_string)# Visualize the word cloud
plt.figure( figsize=(20,10) )
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.show()
```

[Wordcloud example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utvCJ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center.