# How to make run a code with a wordcloud error

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-cloud, wordcloud2

I am trying to do a wordcloud from a a dataframe in Python, however when I tried to run the code it gives me an error message as the following one: NameError: name 'text' is not defined. 
The dataframe is composed of scraped data from a local newspaper and what I want to do is to make a wordcloud with the most mentioned words.

The Data Frame is like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhPc0.jpg)

```
import os
os.chdir("H:\RP3055G001\Estructuracion\Python\Gestion")
df = pd.read_csv("export_dataframe.csv")

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
nltk_sw = stopwords.words('spanish')

from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

wordcloud_2 = WordCloud(stopwords=nltk_sw,background_color='white',width=1400,height=1200).generate(text)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,50))
plt.imshow(wordcloud_2)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: That error means you're trying to use `.generate(text)` but you haven't defined the variable `text` to mean anything

Comment: Bases on the photo that I uploaded lines above, what would be your solution to fix that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate word cloud from single-column Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606339/generate-word-cloud-from-single-column-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: solution is to create variable `text` with words which you want to display in wordcloud - ie. `text = "Hello World of Word Cloud`

Answer (score 0):

Your code's 'text' is not define.
Try this way.

```
text = ''

for i in range(len(df)):
    text += df.iloc[i,2]
```

OR

```
.generate(df.text)
```