# wordlcoud from pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I want to create a wordcloud from a pandas dataframe, but only from one column "Finish the sentence: I buy knifes for... (collection, hunting, fun,, safety,..., etc.).

[image]

For this reason I create a separate Pandas Series "moreuses" which only stores values from this column (number 4) with:

```
moreuses = dataset.iloc[:,4]
moreuses
```

output:

```
0                                      EDC and Outdoors 
1                                    Fishing and hunting
2             Hunting, safety, fun, and for everyday use
3          Purely for use, not for display or collecting
4                                                   fun!
                             ...                        
138                  Everyday carry, cutting misc things
139                                              fun/edc
140                         Utility. Fun, and Collection
141    playing with it like a toy. I'm not really nee...
142    Work, play, defense and somthing beautiful to ...
Name: Finish the sentence: I buy knifes for...  (collection, hunting, fun, safety, ... , etc. ), Length: 143, dtype: object
```

Now I would like to create a wordcloud from these words, but get an error:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

# Read the whole text.
text = moreuses

# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
# the matplotlib way:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# take relative word frequencies into account, lower max_font_size
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white",max_words=len(s),max_font_size=40, relative_scaling=.5).generate(text)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

> **ERROR: TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**

Now I have tried to implement the solution from this stackoverflow post:
[Generate word cloud from single-column Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606339/generate-word-cloud-from-single-column-pandas-dataframe)

However I dont get any output from the proposed code:

```
wordcloud2 = WordCloud().generate(' '.join(moreuses)
```

I believe it is because in this example there are only single words? However I can't seem to figure out the problem... Would appreciate every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First turn your column into a list

```
words = list(moreuses.values())
```

Then join the values

```
string_of_words = " ".join(words)
```

Then generate your word cloud

```
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(string_of_words)
```

Note: Untested, as no sample data was given.

Comment: yes worked great! thanks for the help and you effort. 

FYI: for me " ".join(words), was without the space- just "".join(words)